# Trouble loading Neural Network in new python file (PyTorch)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

Im having issues loading a neural network that has been trained into a new file. I have saved the neural network in Model.py with

`torch.save(model.state_dict(), "model.pth")`

Now in a new file (Test.py) I have the following code:

```
from Model import NeuralNetwork
import torch

model = NeuralNetwork()
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model.pth))
model.eval()
```

However, when I run this file (Test.py), the neural network seems to re-train (I can see epochs being printed again). I'm pretty sure this is not supposed to be happening. If someone could please get back to me about what the issue is that would be amazing! Thank you in advance!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by printing out the epochs again? Nothing in what you have in the your given test.py file should be able to restart training in any capacity. Is there any code after what you have given here?

Answer (score 0):

model.eval() is setting the model to inference mode, I guess You need to pass some input to the model to see the output of your model.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).